# How to boost a facebook post from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, boost

I already have this method to post on a facebook page

```
exports.publish = function(fbToken, post){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        FB.setAccessToken(fbToken);

        FB.api('me/feed', 'post', {message: post.text})
            .then(function(response) {
                resolve(response.id) 
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                    reject(error)
            });
    })
}
```

However, I would like to boost a post and set some kind of audience, budget, and duration, but I can not find the way.

I've been reading: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis
But How can I set the custom boost in a specific post?

Comment: Which kind of SDK, lib do You use?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb

Comment: for Fb Graph API 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I am adding from my [answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288881/4397123) 
Only difference is you will have to call those API's in node js. The requirements and the way to boost the post will remain the same.

*From the Facebook docs :*

For creating an ad from Page post ( boosting a post ), you will first need to create the creative for that ad from the post.
[See the doc page on how to create ad adcreatives.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/) Search for **Create an ad from an existing page post**

After that you will need to create an ad using that creative ad. [Creating ads from API with creative id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/#ads_7)

Hope that helps !